# Best practise to handle different view clicking in the listview item?

Tags: android, listview, click

In order to handle different view clicking, I set listeners for views in getView(). If a lot of items added, it will be a little slow.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            holder.icon_iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon_iv);
            holder.icon_iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ...
                }
            });

            holder.checkbox_iv = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_checkbox_iv);
            holder.checkbox_iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ...
                }
            });
    }
```

So I wanna do it in onItemClick(), but View arg1 can't tell the difference on views clicking. Can anyone tell me what to do with it?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

}
```

EDIT:
Thank you, I decide do like this and it works perfectly:

```
        holder.item_ll.setTag(position);
        holder.item_ll.setOnClickListener(mItemClickListener);
        holder.checkbox_iv.setTag(position);
        holder.checkbox_iv.setOnClickListener(mItemClickListener);

public View.OnClickListener mItemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getTag() instanceof Integer) {
            int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
            HistoryItem item = adapter.get(position);
            if (view.getId() == R.id.checkbox_iv) {
                ...
            } else if (view.getId() == R.id.item_ll) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: the arg2 has the index of list item so you can do any operation using this index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one `OnClickListener` to handle one kind of event

Example code

inside your `Adapter`

```
public interface CustomListListener
{
    void onEventA(index int);
    void onEventB(index int);
}
public View.OnClickListener mButtonATypeClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
        mListener.onEventA(position);
    }
}
public View.OnClickListener mButtonBTypeClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
        mListener.onEventB(position);
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   buttonA.setTag(position);
   buttonA.setOnClickListener(mButtonATypeClickListener);
   buttonB.setTag(position);
   buttonB.setOnClickListener(mButtonBTypeClickListener);
   ...
}
```

Now all you have to do is implement `CustomListListener` in your `Activity`.

Comment: I have "Cannot cast from Object to int" error, it was fixed by casting as Integer instead of int.

Answer (score 3):

You can use getId() function

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

if(arg1.getId()==R.id.app_icon_iv){
             //Do something for that view
}
else{ 
             // Do something for another view
}

}
```

Comment: arg1.getId() can't tell the different view clicking, it always return a constant value.

Comment: You can match that Constant value with the Id of the view and use it

Comment: Ok, I will have a try and let you know later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use tags: you just give each view a tag by setTag() method and then in onClick method you check the tag of the view that has been clicked

Answer (score 1):

If you have common execution on every child of list item, then you have to use `onItemClick()` listner other wise each child have it's own click listener. One more thing is when use you **CheckBox** or **RadioButton** it's better to use their check change listener rather than on click listener.